# How to give multiple input paths to gora avrostore in giraph (or) how to make giraph read multiple input files

Tags: properties, avro, giraph, gora

How do I make giraph read data from multiple input paths.
I am using this in gora.properties

gora.datastore.default = org.apache.gora.avro.store.Avrostore
gora.avrostore.input.path=file:///path/to/file1.avro,file:///path/to/file2.avro

But it gives this error 
Input path does not exist: file:/path/to/file1.avro,file:/path/to/file2.avro

Comment: It seems like the FileInputFormat is unable to split the input path at commas(It is reading it as "\,"),then how do I give the input?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** sorry, but seems not possible.

**Long answer:**

I don't use Giraph, but I know that Gora [does not support multiple paths in AvroStore](https://github.com/apache/gora/blob/master/gora-core/src/main/java/org/apache/gora/avro/mapreduce/FsInput.java#L46).

For that necessity, Giraph should be the one implementing that feature creating 2 DataStore connections (one per each file), but I guess it does not do that (or does it?).

The other approach would be to improve [AvroStore](https://github.com/apache/gora/tree/master/gora-core/src/main/java/org/apache/gora/avro/store) to support several files in the configuration, but as far as I know, you are the first to think about it. Maybe you would want to make that improvement... :)